# RP-PPPoE server rejects IPCP configuration request from PPPoE client

Tags: pppoe

I am using RP-PPPoE 3.11 server.

I am looking for an option in server like "ipcp-accept-remote", 
if PPPoE client sends PPP IPCP Configuration request to server with Option - desired remote IP Address (say - 15.0.0.10), RP-PPPoE server should acknowledge the option requested by client.

Currently I am able to acquire IP address from PPPoE server, if PPPoE client doesnt request desired IP address option to server.

If PPPoE client sends IPCP config request with desired IP address, RP-PPPoE server sends IPCP config-reject.